# Why do my scenes resize in landscape as to not use the entire screen space?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I started a new XCode project using the 'cocos2d iOS' template, and for some reason my view automatically resizes as to not use all of the screen space. My program only supports landscape. There is some extra blacked out space on either side of any scene.

How can I make it so that my program uses all of the available screen space?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on a widescreen device?

It sounds as if you have forgotten to include the `Default-568h@2x.png` image to your project.

If this image is included, the scene doesn't necessarily automatically scale itself to the screen bounds.

I tend to just scale up the background, then just allow for dynamic spacing between other elements on the scene.

You may have to do something like this to scale up certain elements.

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH    ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT   ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height)

CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"background.png"];
background.position = ccp(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
background.scaleX = SCREEN_WIDTH / 480.0f;
background.scaleY = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 320.0f;
[self addChild:background];
```

Comment: Hey James, thanks for your answer. I did indeed include the Default-568h@2x.png - that's the first splash screen the iPhone loads with. However, after a few seconds, it displays what appears to be the Default@2x.png splash screen.

I tried your background scaling up and that worked, however. I'm still just wondering why the splash screen would go from full wide-screen to Default@2x.png